AWS ALB Listen for HTTPS and send to ECS as HTTP
I have an ECS Cluster with a task listening on for HTTP traffic on port 9090.  I want to create an ALB to do the SSL termination and send the request onto the ECS task on port 9090.  I got it to work with the ALB listening on port 80 - but not 443. It's still sending encrypted traffic to ECS. I see errors in the application logs showing the request being a jumbled mess (encrypted).  There's a lot of different ports/target groups/etc and I think I'm just congused as to which to configure correctly:
ALB->Listener[port 443]->Target Group[port 9090]->ECS
Is creating a new ECS Service/Task the only way to make them a target group?  You cannot pick it as an option when creating TGs through that UI.

It sounds to me like you have your target group configured to use HTTPS to the targets.  That's distinct from a setting on the ALB's listener end.

As mentioned above, you have the wrong protocol selected for the targets in your target group. All target group settings should be protocol  HTTP and port 9090. If you already had this working for the load balancer's port 80 listener, then you should have just created another listener on the target group and not made any changes to the target group at all, If you created a separate target group for the other listener, then just delete that target group.

The above comments were correct.  When creating the ECS Service I needed to choose the existing ALB, Create new Listener for HTTPS and then Create new Target Group for HTTP.  I also needed to add my healthcheck path /actuator/health for the TG to register as healthy.
